# How can I write constructor for this class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, properties, constructor

```
class Anything
{
    List<string> PPP = new List<string>()
    { 
        "table", 
        "chair", 
        "spoon", 
        "bread"
    };

    string name;
}
```

`name` must be one of the items in the `PPP`.

```
name = "bed" //must be an error.
```

How should I write property for `name` ?
And consructor for class `Anything` ?

For example I can check out value every time with foreach. But I want to learn that is there another ways? PPP can be added value seldom. Therefore I dont use Enum. 
It is only little part of my program. And I am beginner in OOP.
I dont use database or form. I work in console via oop.

Comment: "PPP can be added value seldom. Therefore I dont use Enum" - I don't understand this reasoning. This feels like a perfect fit for enums...

Comment: Seldom is not "never". I dont know english very well. may be I'm not right.
Can I add item to enum seldom ?

Comment: And thanks for correction my code

Comment: Absolutely. You just change the code. Now all the code needs to be aware that the enum *can* be added to, but that doesn't mean it's the wrong approach - the same is true for your `List<string>`, of course.

Comment: Potentially, but I would probably make the enum value names themselves  English, and either use attributes to include the description, or use a resource lookup for i18n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I write constructor for this class?

```
class Anything
{
    public Anything(string name)
    {
        if(ppp.Contains(name))
            this.name = name;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Name invalid");
    }

    private List<string> ppp = new List<string>()
    { 
        "table", 
        "chair", 
        "spoon", 
        "bread"
    };

    private string name;
}
```

You may have noticed that I have applied some C# conventions to your code:

1. Changed `PPP` to `ppp`. The convention is that private fields be lowerCamelCase.
2. Added explicit access modifiers to your private fields. This is more personal preference.

Comment: Ok, I will.
and Thanks for your answer. it was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can control that in the `set` accessor for `name`:

```
class Anything
{

    public Anything(string name)
    {
        Name = name;   // this will call the `set` accessor
    }
    List<string> PPP = new List<string>()
    { 
        "table", 
        "chair", 
        "spoon", 
        "bread"
    };

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get {return name;}
        set 
        { 
             if (!PPP.Contains(value)) 
                 throw new ArgumentException("value");

             name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If performance is a problem change `List<string>` to `HashSet<string>`.

Comment: He asked for a constructor. His `name` is a private field, not a property.

Comment: @SamLeach added the constructor - and I am using the private field as the backing field for the property.

Comment: @DStanley Yet it's the difference between an immutable and a mutable type.  That's a pretty big difference.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I found my answer and also I learned another things  for your codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Anything
{
    private List<string> PPP = new List<string>()
    { 
        "table", 
        "chair", 
        "spoon", 
        "bread"
    };

    private string _name;

    // Public property to have access for reading it outside the class but 
    // with private setter to set it only inside class
    public string Name {
       get { return _name; } 
       private set { 
           // Use linq to verify name
           if(PPP.Contains(value))
           {
               _name = value;
           }
           else
           {
               string message = string.Format("{0} is not acceptable value!", value)
               throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
           }              
       } 
    };

    // Constructor
    public  Anything(string name)
    {
         this.Name = name;
    }
}
```